# Disable Swipe of Parent TabNavigator when in certain Screens in Nested Navigators

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I have been trying to implement nested Navigators for my app.
The Structure of the app is quite simple.

```
RootNavigation(TabNavigator):
    - Camera
    - HomeNavigation (TabNavigator)
    - MessagesList
```

So the app starts on the `HomeNavigation` on display by default. Swipe Left for `Camera` and swipe Right to `MessagesList`.

Now the `HomeNavigation` is further divided like this:

```
HomeNavigation (TabNavigator):
    - News Feed List
    - NotificationsList
    - Search News
```

In this Navigator, `News Feed List` is shown by default. Now when I go to `NotificationsList` or `Search News` in `Home Navigation`. Swiping Left or Right takes me to `Camera` and `MessagesList` which I don't want. I only want this feature when I am in `News Feed List`. Now I was reading the docs but couldn't quite understand how to disable swiping in the `RootNavigation (Parent Navigator) from inside the child`. Also later in the development stage the `News Feed List` will be converted to a `StackNavigator` where a user can select each news item and read it in full detail. I would also want it to be disabled when going deeper in the `NewsFeedList`.

Maybe this code will help better understand my situation:

**HomeNavigationConfigurtation:**

```
const homeNavigationConfiguration = {
    TabOneNavigation: {
        screen: FeedScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'Home',
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => {
                return (
                    <Ionicons
                        name={focused ? 'ios-home' : 'ios-home-outline'}
                        size={30}
                        style={{ color: tintColor }}
                    />
                );
            }
        }
    },
    TabTwoNavigation: {
        screen: SearchTab,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'Search',
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => {
                return (
                    <Ionicons
                        name={focused ? 'ios-search' : 'ios-search-outline'}
                        size={30}
                        style={{ color: tintColor }}
                    />
                );
            }
        }
    },
    TabThreeNavigation: {
        screen: NotificationTab,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'Notify',
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => {
                return (
                    <Ionicons
                        name={focused ? 'ios-list' : 'ios-list-outline'}
                        size={30}
                        style={{ color: tintColor }}
                    />
                );
            }
        }
    }
};

const tabBarConfiguration = {
    //...other configs
    tabBarComponent: TabBarBottom,
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    swipeEnabled: false,
    animationEnabled: false,
    lazy: true,
    tabBarOptions: {
        showIcon: true,
        showLabel: false,
        activeTintColor: '#347FC4',
        inactiveTintColor: '#929AA1',
        activeBackgroundColor: '#FFF',
        inactiveBackgroundColor: '#FFF'
    }
};

export const HomeNavConfiguration = TabNavigator(routeConfiguration, tabBarConfiguration);
```

**HomeNavigation:**

```
class HomeNavigationextends Component {
    render() {
        const { dispatch, navigationState } = this.props;
        return (
            <HomeNavigationConfiguration
                navigation={
                    addNavigationHelpers({
                        dispatch,
                        state: navigationState,
                    })
                }
            />
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        navigationState: state.homeNavState,
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HomeNavigation);
```

**HomeNavigationReducer:**

```
export default (state, action) => {
    if (action.type === 'JUMP_TO_TAB') {
        return { ...state, index: 0 };
    }
    return HomeNAvigationConfig.router.getStateForAction(action, state);
};
```

**RootNavigationConfiguration:**

```
const routeConfiguration = {
    RootNavigationScreenLeft: {
        screen: CameraScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarVisible: false
        }
    },
    RootNavigationScreenMiddle: {
        screen: RootTab,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarVisible: false
        }
    },
    RootNavigationScreenRight: {
        screen: MessagesListScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarVisible: false
        }
    }
};

const tabBarConfiguration = {
    //...other configs
    swipeEnabled: true,
    animationEnabled: true,
    lazy: true,
    initialRouteName: 'RootNavigationScreenMiddle'
};

export const RootNavigationConfig = TabNavigator(routeConfiguration, tabBarConfiguration);
```

**Root Navigation**

```
class RootNavigationextends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { dispatch, navigationState } = this.props;
        return (
            <RootNavigationConfig
                navigation={
                    addNavigationHelpers({
                        dispatch,
                        state: navigationState,
                    })
                }
            />
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        navigationState: state.rootNavState,
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(RootNavigation);
```

Any solutions or advice will be highly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

From a UX perspective, the user might be confused. What you're basically doing is,

```
RootNavigation (TabNavigator)
- Camera
- News Feed List
- NotificationsList
- Search News
- MessagesList
```

Consider if this works in your case?

```
RootNavigation(StackNavigator):
    - Camera
    - HomeNavigation (TabNavigator)
    - MessagesList

HomeNavigation (TabNavigator):
    - News Feed List
    - NotificationsList
    - Search News
```

As for your question,

> I only want this feature when I am in `News Feed List`

When you setup your navigation, it takes the form `TabNavigator(RouteConfigs, TabNavigatorConfig)`

You can pass `navigationOptions` to both, the `RouteConfigs` and the `TabNavigatorConfig`. The `navigationOptions` that you specify in each `screen` object allows to override the `navigationOptions` in `TabNavigatorConfig`. Basically, you pass 'general' configuration for all screens to `TabNavigatorConfig` `navigationOptions` and `screen-specific` to `RouteConfigs` `navigationOptions`.

Comment: If I use StackNavigator, won't I lose the option of swiping to left and right to access Camera and MessagesList in the RootNavigation?

Comment: O yes. But, that was only a suggestion (to mix Stack and Tab navigator) for probably a cleaner UX design. If you are still looking to swipe between all screens, why don't you simple wrap all the 5 screens under  a TabNavigator only? The `HomeNavigation` categorisation seems redundant.

Comment: Well I first did that and then I also kept the StackNavigator as the RootNavigation, but swiping left and right seemed better than having a button which will do the same job, so I changed the RootNavigation as TabNavigator. It gave a better animation when you see the camera coming in.